# C linked list incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct list_node {
    int value;
    struct list_node *next;
};

struct linked_list {
    int size;
    struct list_node *head;
};

void print_linked_list(struct linked_list *list){
    struct linked_list *current = list;

    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%d ", current->head->value);
        current = current->head->next;
    }
}
```

I have to define a function to print out a linked list, but I get an error message saying "incompatible pointer type". I know that the problem is in "current = current->head->next;" but how can I achieve that?

Comment: You need `struct list_node *curr = list->head;` in place of `struct linked_list *current = list;`, and consequential changes in the loop (`while (curr != NULL) { printf("%d ", curr->value); curr= curr->next; }`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current` is a `struct linked_list*`, but `current->head->next` is a `struct list_node*`.

`struct linked_list` and `struct list_node` are two different unrelatd structures in spite of their similarity.

You cannot assign pointers to different types, hence the error message *incompatible pointer type*.

You probably want this:

```
void print_linked_list(struct linked_list* list) {
  struct list_node* current = list->head;

  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("%d ", current->value);
    current = current->next;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
void print_linked_list(struct linked_list *list){
    struct linked_list *current = list;

    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%d ", current->head->value);
        current = current->head->next;
    }
}
```

does not make a sense.

In this statement

```
current = current->head->next;
```

the pointer `current` has the type `struct linked_list *` while the expression `current->head->next` has the type `struct list_node *`.

It seems you mean

```
void print_linked_list( const struct linked_list *list )
{
    if ( list != NULL )
    {
        for ( const struct list_node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
        {
            printf( "%d ", current->value );
        }
    }
}
```